# Doctor Who slit scan

Tags: modeling, animation, texturing, transforms, animation-nodes

[image]I've crafted my shape and added an image texture but how to I apply motion to the still image texture? I want the image to loop (seamlessly)

I'm trying to recreate the 1974 Doctor Who sequence[image: example image from Doctor Who]

Comment: Hello, hard to answer, you don't give enough information, please pack your image and share your file, or show some screenshots?

Comment: The image texture will have to be tileable, or made tileable, one way or another.. that means we have to know about your mapping, your general approach so far. Please share on https://blend-exchange.com/ , as moonboots has suggested, or we don't have a lot to go on.

Comment: @moonboots I have updated the question with images

Comment: If you are using an image texture make sure that it is seamless?

Comment: @moonboots Its seamless enough, its that I can't get it into motion

Comment: in that case simply keyframe the Y location value in the Mapping node?

Comment: @moonboots It simply distorts the image, not give it motion

Comment: Could you please pack your image (File > External Data > Pack Resources) and share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/ or use another platform like workupload